# update column with trigger in postgres

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have this code for my table asf with column **price** and a column **category**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION aft_update()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
UPDATE asf SET price = new.price='300' WHERE category = 'pro';
RETURN NEW;
END;

$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER updt_log
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON asf
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE aft_update();
```

but for some reason even though the trigger runs successfully, the update does not work! I want to update multiple rows.

Comment: what Do you try to do with `SET price = new.price='300'`

Comment: I already have a price filled in the column price (for example 400) and I want to change all prices under category pro to 300

Comment: Why do you want to change rows that are not affected by the UPDATE?

Comment: your query doesn't nake sense you have a trigger oin asf and write also a log for it in the same table? this should be another table

Comment: I want to change the price column, not the category one. I only use the category column to specify where I want the change to be

Answer (score 1):

For that you don't need any trigger or function at all

> ```
> CREATE TABLE asf (id serial, price DECIMAL(10,2),category varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO asf (price,category) VALUES (10.2,'pro'),(11.2,'pro')
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE asf SET price = 300 where category = 'pro'
> ```

2 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM asf
> ```
>
> ```
> id |  price | category
> -: | -----: | :-------
>  1 | 300.00 | pro     
>  2 | 300.00 | pro
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a2f44c3f4e6b758803bcb9b44a091299)*

Comment: I know a trigger is not necessary but I was trying to use one and cant figure out why it's not functioning!

Comment: so you trigger the trigger after an update and the function updates which triggers the after update trigger and so on and so on